# Generate md5 checksum for all files in a directory

Tags: command-line

I would like to create a md5 checksum list for all files in a directory.

I want to `cat filename | md5sum > ouptput.txt`. I want to do this in 1 step for all files in my directory.

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: ``` find . -type f -exec md5sum {} > md5sums.txt \; ```
this is all you need!

Comment: Or rather: `find . -type f -exec md5sum {} > {}.md5sum \;`

Comment: In case one wants to include subdirectories but do separate checksum files inside each subdir, this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71286224/111036

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You can pass `md5sum` multiple filenames or bash expansions:

```
$ md5sum * > checklist.chk  # generates a list of checksums for any file that matches *
$ md5sum -c checklist.chk   # runs through the list to check them
cron: OK
database.sqlite3: OK
fabfile.py: OK
fabfile.pyc: OK
manage.py: OK
nginx.conf: OK
uwsgi.ini: OK
```

If you want to get fancy you can use things like `find` to drill down and filter the files, as well as working recursively:

```
find -type f -exec md5sum "{}" + > checklist.chk
```

Comment: ♦ how to use the above for getting `md5sum` of the files inside sub directories, the above `md5sum *` emitting going into subdirectory level by saying ... is a directory

Comment: Sorry for asking by running `find -type f -exec md5sum '{}' +` and `find -type f -exec md5sum '{}' \` I was able to get it. Thanks :)

Comment: I prefer the look of this output more: `openssl md5 * > checklist.txt`

Comment: If you're using a shell that's happy to evaluate `**` recursively (such as zsh), it's even simpler: `md5sum **/* 2>/dev/null`

Comment: if the process will take a while, you can run it through `pv` to track progress. use it in line mode w/ `pv -l`: `find . -type f -exec md5sum '{}' \; | pv -l -s $(find . -type f | wc -l) > ~/md5sum.txt` ...just make sure both of your `find` filters match: the main one and the one in the pv subshell

Answer (score 26):

A great checksum creation/verification program is [`rhash`](https://github.com/rhash/RHash).

- It can create SFV compatible files, and check them too.
- It supports md4, md5, sha1, sha512, crc32 and many many other.
- It can do recursive creation (`-r` option) like `md5deep` or `sha1deep`.
- Last but not least, you can format the output of the checksum file. For example:

  ```
  rhash --md5 -p '%h,%p\n' -r /home/ > checklist.csv
  ```

  outputs a CSV file including the full path of files recursively starting with the `/home` directory.

I also find the `-e` option to rename files by inserting crc32 sum into the name extremely useful.

Note that you can also change `md5sum` with `rhash` in the [PhoenixNL72 examples](https://askubuntu.com/a/327065/618353).

Comment: What exactly does '/home/' do here? This tool looks pretty good.

Comment: I think it's an error, it certainly errors for me. The -p is the format for the output. I'll correct it.

Comment: /home/ is the path to start the process from, i.e. create checksums for all files under /home/

Answer (score 8):

Here are two more extensive examples:

1. Create an md5 file in each directory which doesn't already have one, with absolute paths:

   ```
   find "$PWD" -type d | sort | while read dir; do [ ! -f "${dir}"/@md5Sum.md5 ] && echo "Processing " "${dir}" || echo "Skipped " "${dir}" " @md5Sum.md5 already present" ; [ ! -f "${dir}"/@md5Sum.md5 ] &&  md5sum "${dir}"/* > "${dir}"/@md5Sum.md5 ; chmod a=r "${dir}"/@md5Sum.md5;done
   ```
2. Create an md5 file in each folder which doesn't already have one: no paths, only filenames:

   ```
   find "$PWD" -type d | sort | while read dir; do cd "${dir}"; [ ! -f @md5Sum.md5 ] && echo "Processing " "${dir}" || echo "Skipped " "${dir}" " @md5Sum.md5 allready present" ; [ ! -f @md5Sum.md5 ] &&  md5sum * > @md5Sum.md5 ; chmod a=r "${dir}"/@md5Sum.md5 ;done
   ```

What differs between 1 and 2 is the way the files are presented in the resulting md5 file.

The commands do the following:

1. Build a list of directory names for the current folder. (Tree)
2. Sort the folder list.
3. Check in each directory if the file @md5sum.md5 exists. Output Skipped if it exists, output Processing if it doesn't exist.
4. If the @md5Sum.md5 file doesn't exist, md5Sum will generate one with the checksums of all the files in the folder.
   5) Set the generated @md5Sum.md5 file to read only.

The output of this entire script can be redirected to a file (.....;done > test.log)
or piped to another program (like grep).
The output will only tell you which directories where skipped and which have been processed.

After a successful run, you will end up with an @md5Sum.md5 file in each subdirectory of your current directory

I named the file @md5Sum.md5 so it'll get listed at the top of the directory in a samba share.

Verifying all @md5Sum.md5 files can be done by the next commands:

```
find "$PWD" -name @md5Sum.md5 | sort | while read file; do cd "${file%/*}"; md5sum -c @md5Sum.md5; done > checklog.txt
```

Afterwards you can grep the checklog.txt using grep -v OK to get a list of all files that differ.

To regenerate an @md5Sum.md5 in a specific directory, when you changed or added files for instance, either delete the @md5Sum.md5 file or rename it and run the generate command again.

Comment: Command #1 using full paths: md5sum "${dir}"/* is not picking up hidden files starting with dot. Any remedy ?

Comment: Late to the party, but since md5sum wants file names (seems uhappy if you give it a directory) it  might be easiest to ask find for help: $ md5sum $( find "$dir" -maxdepth 0 -type f  )
The "-type f" pulls regular and .hidden files (also, find has many options, but can be super helpful).
Omit the "-maxdepth 0"  part if you want everything recursively.
Note: this is fragile if the filenames have embedded spaces, then you can read up on xargs and -0  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs )

Answer (score 4):

I hit this issue, and while the solutions above are elegant, I wanted a quick and dirty hack for this situation: 1 directory, with subdirectories one level deep inside it.

So, enter the directory in a shell and run:

```
md5sum * */* 2>/dev/null > md5sum.md5
```

This gets all the files in the top level directory, removes the error warning about the sub directories being directories, and then runs md5sums on the subdirectory contents. Advantage: easy to remember, does exactly what it's supposed to do. I always get confused by find syntax and can never remember it off the top of my head, so no need to loop etc, dealing with spaces in directory names, this one liner worked fine. Not a robust powerful solution, no good for > 1 level of subdirectories, but a quick and easy fix for the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's mine:

```bsh
time find dirname/|xargs md5sum |tee dirname.md5
```

It throws errors when it tries to calculate it for a directory, but it's good enough for me.

Comment: Do 2> /dev/null to ignore error due to directory.

Comment: Or add "-type f" on the find command to exclude directories.

Answer (score 2):

The [rclone](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_hashsum/) utility has this functionality and it's available from `sudo apt install rclone`

You can run it with:

```
rclone hashsum MD5 <dirname>
```

You can also run other fun hashes such as:

- md5
- sha1
- whirlpool
- crc32
- sha256
- dropbox
- hidrive
- mailru
- quickxor

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop:

```
for i in *; do md5sum $i > $i.md5; done
```