# Generate a separate .md5 file for each .fastq file in a directory?

Tags: md5sum, checksums

I am trying to generate separate .md5 files for each .fastq file in a directory. I found solutions to generate a single .md5 file for many files, but this is not what I am looking for.

I have `file1.fastq`, `file2.fastq`, `file3.fastq` and want to generate `file1.md5`, `file2.md5`, `file3.md5`.

I assume that a FOR loop would do the trick but I am not a programmer and can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

I also tried the following code:

```
find . -type f -name "*.fastq.gz" -exec sh -c "md5sum < {} > {}.md5" \;
```

It correctly generates an .md5 file for each .fastq file, but the .md5 file contents are incorrect, i.e. I get `64399513b7d734ca90181b27a62134dc   -`

instead of `64399513b7d734ca90181b27a62134dc testfile.fastq`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Answers to http://askubuntu.com/questions/318530/generate-md5-checksum-for-all-files-in-a-directory  post only explain how to generate a single .md5 file for many files

Comment: Hang on, are your files `*fastq` or `*fastq.gz`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest case is:

```
for file in *fastq; do md5sum "$file" > "$file".md5; done
```

That, however, will create file names like `file1.fastq.md5`. Extensions are basically irrelevant here, so that isn't a problem, but if you prefer `file1.md5` do this instead:

```
for file in *fastq; do md5sum "$file" > "${file//.fastq}".md5; done
```

Comment: The first option is exactly what I needed. Thanks terdon!

Answer (score 3):

Also your `md5sum` command doesn't print the filename because each file is read from the shell due to the `<` redirection, and `md5sum` can't possibly know the original filename, since it's feeded the file's content directly.

So if you want to process all the files in the current working directory recursively you can use this command instead:

```
find . -type f -name "*.fastq.gz" -exec sh -c "md5sum {} > {}.md5" \;
```