# Generate a separate .md5 file for each file in a directory, while SKIPPING existing ones

Tags: find, md5sum

I got say 4TB of millions of files.
I think if I can produce a single .md5 for each file,
it would be nice.

I read 
[Generate a separate .md5 file for each .fastq file in a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727097/generate-a-separate-md5-file-for-each-fastq-file-in-a-directory)
and modified to make it produce an individual .md5 for EACH individual file.

say :
find . -type f -name "*" -exec sh -c "md5sum {} > {}.md5" \;

But as I say I got 4TB of millions of files,
the command may not finish in 2 days and I have to shutdown the PC.

when resume, I wish the above command could skip those files that
already have existing .md5 files (i.e. those calculated).

How to do this?
recursively, of course.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than create one `.md5` file per file ("millions of files"), using up millions of disk clusters and millions of inodes, put `.md5` signatures for all files in one big file (which you can split up later, if you wish)(read `man find;man xargs`):

```
find . -type f \! -name '*.md5' -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > md5sum.out
#   Separate filenames with \000^^^^^^^          ^ in case some have spaces
#              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ but NOT *.md5 files
#      ^^^^^^^ each file
```