# How to check md5 for folder with files?

Tags: bash, md5sum

I want to compare local folder and folder on server, folder can contain subfolders and subfolders can contain files.

How to compute md5sum for whole folder?

**Update:**

One possible solution will not to compute hash for whole folder, but to compute hash for each file and then compare lists of hashes.

Lets assume we want to compare folders `a` and `b`:

```
tree .
.
├── a
│   ├── 1.txt
│   └── d
│       └── 2.txt
└── b
    └── 1.txt
```

This can show the difference:

```
find a -type f | sort | xargs md5 -r | cut -f1 -d " " > a.txt
find b -type f | sort | xargs md5 -r | cut -f1 -d " " > b.txt
git diff --no-index a.txt b.txt
```

But how to check which file corresponds to hash that is missing from one of the folders?

If I

```
cd a
find . -type f | sort | xargs md5 -r > ../a.txt
cd ..
cd b
find . -type f | sort | xargs md5 -r > ../b.txt
cd ..
git diff --no-index a.txt b.txt
```

This solves a problem, however maybe not very elegant.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/318534/333714

Comment: This seems an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/300917) and probably [a duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/q/421712/349837). To compare directories recursively you can use [`diff` over `ssh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20969709/4970442) or [`rsync`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19410791/4970442). You really need to use `md5sum`? If so, try the globbing operator: `md5sum **`

Answer (score 2):

The solution with zip in other answer look good, but for me have some disadvantages, it need to zip the files, do not show which file is different.

Because of this I will offer one sample solution:

```
cd /target/directory
md5sum * >/tmp/tmp_file
```

If you have subdirectories and files and want to include those files too use

```
cd /target/directory
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; >/tmp/tmp_file
```

transfer `tmp_file` to other server and execute there

```
cd /remote_target/directory
md5sum -c /tmp/tmp_file
```

(if `tmp_file` is transferred in `/tmp` directory)
and you will see output like this:

```
[root@rh1 sssd]# md5sum -c /tmp/a
./sssd.log: OK
./sssd_implicit_files.log: OK
./sssd_nss.log: OK
./a/aa: OK
```

Comment: `md5sum *` not working if `/target/directory` contains folders.

Comment: @mrgloom, you change the question! See my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Using rhash to output md5 hashes to file.

```
$ rhash -Mr -o /path/to/md5sum .
```

Verify hash from files.

```
$ rhash -c /path/to/md5sum
```

[rhash](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/rhash.1.html) options:

- `-M` MD5: calculate and print MD5 hash sum.
- `-r` Recursively process directories, specified by command line.
- `-o`  Set the file to output calculated hashes and verification results.
- `-c` Check hash files specified by command line.

Saving directory structure to the same file.

```
$ find -type d -printf "; %P\n" >> /path/to/md5sum1
```

Compare files line by line.

```
$ diff md5sum1 md5sum2
```